# How to login to Postgres after install on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I got Postgres 8.4 installed on my mac with Snow Leopard. I know the 'postgres' user was created but I have no idea what the default password is. How should I login to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2001-10/msg00192.php and similar internet resources may answer your question. Supposedly, there is no password by default.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think the problem was caused by a previous installation. I have been working with the pg_hba.conf and am close to getting it working.

Comment: Once you do get it working, would you like to post your configuration file(s)? This will help out future users.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers...

I had a similar problem. After installing Postgres 9.1, the password I supplied to the installer didn't allow me to connect to the database using pgadmin 3. This is what I had to do  to fix it:

1. **Configure so you can log in without a password:**

   1. Stop the postgres server (launch daemon):

      - sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.1.plist
   2. Edit data/pg_hba.conf and change 'md5' to 'trust' in the 'local'
      '127.0.0.1/32' line.
   3. Start the daemon

      - sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.1.plist
2. **Connect using pgadmin 3 and re-set the password**

   1. Start pgadmin 3 and connect to the database (right click 'Connect' on the Postgres 9.1 server).
   2. Under Login roles, right-click the 'posgres' user, select 'Properties...' and reset the password on the 'Definition' tab panel.
   3. Then disconnect pgadmin 3 from the database (right-click 'Disconnect' on the Postgres 9.1 server).
3. **Configure the server so it requires a password again:**

   1. Stop the daemon (as per step 1.1).
   2. Edit data/pg_hba.conf and change 'trust' back to 'md5' in the
      'local' '127.0.0.1/32' line.
   3. Start the daemon (as per step 1.3).